# Difference between NOUN + から, NOUN + で and NOUN + だから to indicate reason

Tags: nuances

> A) 彼女は**疲れから**病気になった。
>
> > She become ill from fatigue.

> B) **病気で**仕事に行けません。
>
> > I can't go to work due to illness.

> C) 明日は**休みだから**どこかへ遊びに行こう。
>
> > Tomorrow is a holiday. So let's go somewhere to have fun.

By using から in A, it's implied that being fatigued lead to becoming sick, but it's not the direct cause: perhaps your immune system weakened and only then you caught a cold. On the other hand, for で and だから there's no such implication: it's taken as a direct cause. Moreover, から and で are neutral, while だから suggests a subjective reasoning.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(C) is a compound sentence unlike the others: 明日は休みだ+から+どこかへ遊びに行こう. So it is から after all.

Regarding で and から, the following is from [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/17136/meaning/m0u/)

> **で／から／に の使い分け**
>
> １ある事態が生じたときの原因・理由は、一般に「で」で表わす。
>
> ２その原因を事態の発生源としてとらえ、因果関係を問題にするような場合には、原因を「から」で表わす。
>
> ３原因というよりは、心理・生理作用の対象としてとらえる場合には、それを「に」で表わす。

|  | 不注意…事故を起こす | 会社を風邪…休む | 疲れ…病気になる | 税金対策…苦しむ | バス…酔う |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| で | ○ | ○ | △ | ○ | △ |
| から | ○ | － | ○ | － | － |
| に | － | － | － | ○ | ○ |

As suggested by the above, it is safer to use で. Your understanding about use of から should be correct, but 因果関係を問題にする is not so clear-cut.